# Объясните постановку запятой.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте!

Есть предложение:

> Он вдруг весь вспыхнул**,** и голос у него стал тверже

Объясните доступно, пожалуйста, почему перед союзом И стоит запятая?

Насколько я понимаю, тут 2 грамматические основы и вторая часть(т. е. вторя грамматическая основа) является придаточным изъяснительным, верно? Так почему тогда запятая?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из двух простых предложений, соединенных союзом И, поэтому запятая ставится.

Запятая может отсутствовать только  в виде исключения.При наличии общего элемента (второстепенный член, частица, вводное слово и др. ) простые предложения в составе ССП с помощью союзов И, ДА=И, ИЛИ, ЛИБО объединяются в единое целое, произносятся без паузы, и запятая между ними не ставится, например:   Всю ночь шёл дождь и бушевал ветер.

Comment: Как определить, что это сложносичиненное?

Comment: Сходные по содержанию сообщения мы можем оформить разными способами, например: А) Приходит весна, и природа оживает. Это ССП (сложносоч.предл.) с сочинительным союзом И, который передает временную последовательность событий. б) Когда приходит весна, природа оживает. Это СПП (сложноподч. предл.) с подчинительным союзом времени КОГДА. В этом случае второе предложение мы делаем главным в нашем сообщении, а первое считаем придаточным (зависимым). Таким образом, различаются ССП и СПП по виду союзов (соч. и подч.) и по структуре: главное предложение + придаточное предложение.

Comment: Ваше предложение можно представить только в  виде ССП с сочинительным союзом И.  Союз И связывает два разных события, отнесенных к одному моменту времени.

Answer (score 2):

> вторая часть(т. е. вторя грамматическая основа) является придаточным изъяснительным, верно?

Неверно. Придаточное предложение - это чаcть сложного предлождения, зависимая от главной.
У нас нет зависмой части.

И вообще, придаточнуе присоединяются с помощью подчинительных собзов, а И - союз сочинительный.

А вопрос про запятую вообще не поняла. Для сложноподчиненных предложений запятые точно так же нужны, как и для сложносочиненных. Кроме одного хитрого случая общего члена.

Comment: Я думал, что при постановки союза запятая не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Типичное ССП, где перед сочинительным союзом ставится запятая, отделяющая две части союзного предложения